# countdown timer is not working while creating coming soon page

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display a countdown timer for coming soon webpage. Everything is working fine except for the timer that is written in javascript. I also tried by making it an external file. It also reads the file when making external but the timer is not shown on the page.

This is my blade file

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title> Coming Soon</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('css/style.css')}}">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Balsamiq+Sans:ital@1&family=Montserrat&family=Open+Sans+Condensed:wght@300&family=Playfair+Display&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <div class="soon">
        <p> We will be back with beautiful website</p>
    <h1>COMING SOON</h1>

    <hr>
    <p id="launch"></p>
</header>

<script>
var date = new Date("Jan 1, 2020 00:00:00").getTime();
    var countdownfunction = setInterval(function() {
      var today = new Date().getTime();
      var distance = date - today;  
      var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
      + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownfunction);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
      }
    }, 1000);
</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

And this is css

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}
header 
{
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),url('/images/comingsoon.jpg'); 
    height: 100vh;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;

}

.soon {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Balsamiq Sans', cursive;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;

}
h1 {
    font-size: 60px;
    letter-spacing: 15px;
}
hr{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 30px auto;
    border: 1.5px solid #fff;
}
p{
    font-size:20px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by it's not working?

Comment: countdown timer is not displaying on the webpage

Comment: any error in the console?

Comment: yes... the error is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null error" on code "document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h ""

Comment: one look at your code, the date is `Jan 1`, your date is already expired. and there's no demo id, only `launch`. you can't see anything because you don't understand the code. don't just copy paste anything on the web

Comment: that was for testing on expired case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add a tag with id demo like a div 
and also your future date is wrong

```
<header>
    <div class="soon">
        <p> We will be back with beautiful website</p>
    <h1>COMING SOON</h1>

    <hr>
    <div id=demo></div>div>
    <p id="launch"></p>
</header>
```

your date is expired change it to something in the future

```
var date = new Date("Jan 1, 2021 00:00:00").getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

change `<p id="launch"></p>` to `<p id="demo"></p>` on html code, 
or change `document.getElementById("demo")` to `document.getElementById("launch")` on script code